# Trying to perform an index search for user's (django-haystack)

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I'm using `django-haystack`. I've written small code which search the state and country from `UserProfile`. If i search state/country then It works like charm. But if I search the `user` then it does not showing any result. Am I missing something? thanks

```
class UserProfileIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user', faceted=True)
    state = indexes.CharField(model_attr='state') 
    country = indexes.CharField(model_attr='country', null=True) 


def get_model(self):
    return UserProfile

def index_queryset(self):
    return self.get_model().objects.all()

def prepare_author(self, obj):
    return "%s <%s>" % (obj.user.get_full_name(), obj.user.email)
```

Here url

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().facet('author')      
urlpatterns += patterns('haystack.views',
    url(r'^search/', FacetedSearchView(form_class=FacetedSearchForm, searchqueryset=sqs), name='haystack_search'),
)
```

Comment: Was the issue resolved or not ?

Comment: @AmarpreetSinghSaini Its very old post. I don't remember.sorry

Answer (score 1):

what is content of your data template have you included something like

```
{{object.user}}
```

in data template (UserProfile_text file ) . What ever is defined in data template is searched from the index.

Answer (score 0):

How's your `UserProfile` defined?

Also note that your `repare_author(self, obj)` will break once you have users with non-ASCII symbols in their names. Return a `u"..."` String instead.